# Notification Manager getSystemService() call not working

Tags: java, android

I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification) tutorial on creating notifications

However, I cannot seem to do the following:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

Because my Android studio reports the error:

```
Required Type: Context
Provided: Class <android.app.NotificationManager>
reason: Class<NotificationManager> is not compatible with Context
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use `getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)`.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this was my solution:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```